# ¿Qué son las "almorroides"?

Tags: palabras-raras

No aparece en el diccionario de la lengua, pero he encontrado el siguiente texto en un foro:

> Además el tuvo un accidente grave y ha estado enfermo de **las almorroides**.

Google parece indicar que es una variante de **hemorroides** pero no encuentro ninguna referencia "fiable"

Comment: Podría ser una mezcla entre "[almorranas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=20cGojR)" y "hemorroides", dos palabras que significan lo mismo, pero no entiendo qué tienen que ver con sufrir un accidente grave.

Comment: I think this poor soul experienced two separate problems -- the accident and the almorroides (my guess is hemorrhoids).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo, creo que tu comentario es la respuesta es correcta, y deberías ponerlo como respuesta. La referencia al accidente grave creo que no aporta sin el contexto. Es más una "pista falsa" que un dato verdaderamente relevante para la traducción.

Comment: Además de estar confundido en el nombre de la enfermedad, está pensando que _las_ almorroides son varios órganos aquejados. No debería usar el artículo "las", a menos que esté hablando de la enfermedad en general.

Comment: @Rodrigo: yo pensaría en un plurale tantum (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum) (donde se menciona hemorroides) o en la posibilidad de más de un almohadón hemorroidal afectado simultáneamente (que es muy común)

Comment: @Wences claro que sí. A lo que yo me refería (de modo poco claro) es que no se está "enfermo de las hemorroides", como si estuviera enfermo de los pulmones, sino que se "tiene una enfermedad llamada hemorroides".

Comment: ¡Ah! Sí es por eso, entonces sí, se puede "estar enfermo" (tener una patología, o afección) en las hemorroides, porque hemorroides también es sinónimo de almohadón (o cojín, o cojinete) hemorroidal. Y de esos tenemos tres: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemorroides  Era a lo que me refería también de forma poco clara con la segunda alternativa que ofrecí.

Answer (score 8):

Tiene toda la pinta de ser una mezcla entre dos términos que significan exactamente lo mismo: [***Almorranas***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=20cGojR) y [***hemorroides***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=K9Amzqw) (el diccionario traduce la primera directamente como sinónimo de la segunda). Dado que las partes centrales de ambas palabras contienen *-morr-* es fácil confundirlas y acabar diciendo *almorroides*.

También podría haber sido *hemorranas*. :-)